# Downloading slows down computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, cpu-usage, intel-core-i3

I have just completed my build this morning and I wanted to see how fast it is.
So I opened up steam and launched borderlands 2(which I pretty much abandoned) and Fusion 360 (it is a workstation build). Borderlands 2 ran fine so I looked up steam for another game to test and I chose Destiny 2, I was downloading it and opened up Fusion 360 to see if it is faster there but it performed worse than my previous pc which used an outdated AMD A6-3600, it takes minutes for it to load a simple file and the UI freezes every time it loads. I checked the CPU status with HWmonitor and the abstract details are as follows:

- Intel i3-9100f, 31% usage 4Ghz(full turbo), no thread higher than 46%, temp under 55C
- AMD RX 5500XT, basically idle
- Ram 4GB used of 16GB
- Windows 10, Energy set to high performance 520W PSU
- The steam library is NTFS transparent compressed
- Fusion 360 takes ~3-4 minutes to start and load files

When I paused downloading Destiny 2, the performance increased and all the files opened up instantly, I have checked the forums and posts and most of them are all driver issues and single core problems but I cannot find relevant post about multitasking reducing CPU performance. I thought that is the CPU is taking its time compressing the files, HWmonitor should show a higher CPU usage. I want to know more about the mechanics of it because I have no idea how OSes allocate resources.

Comment: Maybe the bottleneck is not your CPU but HDD / SSD?

Comment: possibly, but now I realized that it could be a network issue and Windows did not allocate enough bandwidth for Fusion 360. Even though I am torrenting, the hdds should still be fast enough and the network cache for fusion is stored in the system drive while the games and torrents are stored in another physical drive.